# I have a small test project with custom UIStoryboardSegue objects, but the animation has a black shadow. Any way to remove it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

I am developing a small test project in Xcode 10 for iOS. I am basically testing custom UIStoryboardSegues. I have prepared a [test project](https://github.com/alfonsotesauro/Test-With-Storyboards-and-UIStoryboardSegue/tree/master) to demonstrate the misbehaviour.

During the segue animations, a black shadow shows on screen. You can see it in the test project because I have set the animation time to 5 seconds.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the view's changing opacity near the beginning and end of the animation, so the "shadow" you're seeing is actually the backing window. While it might not be perfect, a quick fix is to change the background color of your window to match the background color of your destination view controller (then set it back after the transition completes if needed).

i.e.:

```
// hold onto the previous window background color
UIColor *previousWindowBackgroundColor = sourceViewController.view.window.backgroundColor;
// switch the window background color to match the destinationController's background color temporarily
sourceViewController.view.window.backgroundColor = destinationController.view.backgroundColor;
// do the transition
[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
// switch the window color back after the transition duration from above
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // make sure we still have a handle on the destination controller
    if (destinationController) {
        destinationController.view.window.backgroundColor = previousWindowBackgroundColor;
    }
});
```

You'll also need to switch the animation to the sourceView's layer:

```
[sourceViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

But this is really just a workaround to make it look slightly better.  Instead of using custom Storyboard Segues I would **highly** recommend using Custom Animators which will give you much more control over the animation transition.

My answer here: [IOS/Objective-C: Possible to Use Custom Segue in Modal Transition in Absence of a Storyboard Segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394928/ios-objective-c-possible-to-use-custom-segue-in-modal-transition-in-absence-of/52396398#52396398) has a full example of custom SlideUp/SlideDown animators.

And here's links to the documentation for it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning?language=objc