# Crossfade transition dips to black when transitioning between 2 white ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm presenting the next viewcontroller modally using a segue with transition set to cross dissolve, but although the source VC and the destination VC backgrounds are white, the screen dips to black at the end of the transition, Any way to make it dip to clear instead of black?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a good question should contain your code or simplified example code displaying the issue you're running into. The gif is helpful to display what you're seeing, but without the context of your code, you're going to get downvotes and receive a lot fewer answers (plus the answers you receive will mostly be speculation/assumptions, like mine's about to be).

My guess is what you're seeing is the view's changing opacity near the beginning and end of the animation, so "when the screen dips to black" you're seeing the backing window. While it might not be perfect, a quick fix is to change the background color of your window to match the background color of your destination view controller (then set it back after the transition completes if needed).

```
// within your perform method for the transition
// hold onto the previous window background color
UIColor *previousWindowBackgroundColor = sourceViewController.view.window.backgroundColor;
// switch the window background color to match the destinationController's background color temporarily
sourceViewController.view.window.backgroundColor = destinationController.view.backgroundColor;
...
// perform the transition
// switch the window color back after the transition duration from above
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // make sure we still have a handle on the destination controller
    if (destinationController) {
        destinationController.view.window.backgroundColor = previousWindowBackgroundColor;
    }
});
```

### Recommendation instead of custom segue transitions:

Use a custom animation transition workflow by creating your own animators as outlined in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396398/7833793

The answer shows a custom animator for a slide up/down animation, but it should give you a clear idea of how to do it for a cross fade as well.